# Matrix muliply fails while creating the model view port transformation

Tags: c++, model-view-controller, matrix, directx

I am current trying to get the right model view port transformation. But when i try to multiplay my sprite Matrix with the viewport matrix it fails but both matrix look fine.

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00B4A67B in Project.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFF.
```

Fails at line 239 of xnamathmatrix.inl

```
// Perform the opertion on the first row
vX = _mm_mul_ps(vX,M2.r[0]);
```

But both vX and MR.r look fine.

Take a look at the render method where it fails:

```
void FirstScreen::render()
{
    if (m_d3dContext == 0)
        return;
    float clearColor[4] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.25f, 1.0f };

    m_d3dContext->ClearRenderTargetView(m_backBufferTarget, clearColor);

    unsigned int stride = sizeof(VertexPos);
    unsigned int offset = 0;

    //setup for sprite. Inputlayout stays how it is
    m_d3dContext->IASetInputLayout(m_inputLayout);
    //set vertexes
    m_d3dContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &sprite.m_vertexBuffer, &stride, &offset);
    m_d3dContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);
    //set shader
    m_d3dContext->VSSetShader(m_vertexShader, 0, 0);
    m_d3dContext->PSSetShader(m_pixelShader, 0, 0);
    //set shader resource
    m_d3dContext->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &sprite.m_texture);
    m_d3dContext->PSSetSamplers(0, 1, &sprite.m_sampler);

    //now before we draw add the right projection
    XMMATRIX world = sprite.getWorldMatrix();
    printMatrix(world); //print the matrix
    printMatrix(m_viewportMatrix); // print the matrix

    XMMATRIX modelViewPort = XMMatrixMultiply(world, m_viewportMatrix); // <---- fails
    modelViewPort = XMMatrixTranspose(modelViewPort);
    //update the resources
    m_d3dContext->UpdateSubresource(m_modelViewPortBuffer, 0, 0, &modelViewPort, 0, 0);
    m_d3dContext->VSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &m_modelViewPortBuffer);

    //draw the 6 vertexes of the sprite
    m_d3dContext->Draw(6, 0);

    m_swapChain->Present(0, 0);
}
```

Here is the creation of the `m_viewportMatrix`:

```
bool FirstScreen::createViewPortMatrix(){
    XMMATRIX view = XMMatrixIdentity();
    XMMATRIX projection = XMMatrixOrthographicOffCenterLH(0.0f, std::atof(m_config->getConfigValue("width")), 0.0f, std::atof(m_config->getConfigValue("height")), 0.1f, 100.0f);
    m_viewportMatrix = XMMatrixMultiply(view, projection);
    return true;
}
```

And here is the method to get the World Matrix from the sprite:

```
XMMATRIX CustomSprite::getWorldMatrix()
{
    XMMATRIX translation = XMMatrixTranslation(m_position.x, m_position.y, 0.0f);
    XMMATRIX rotation = XMMatrixRotationZ(m_rotation);
    XMMATRIX scale = XMMatrixScaling(m_scale.x, m_scale.y, 1.0f);
    return translation*rotation*scale;
}
```

if i run it i get the following matrixes whish should be multiply and fail at the line inside of the render:

```
1 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0
100 300 0 1
```

and

```
0.001042 0 0 0
0 0.001389 0 0
0 0 0.010010 0
-1 -1 -0.001001 1
```

so whats going wrong here?

**If needed i can upload the code somewhere to check whats wrong.** (around 6cpp + h)

---

**UPDATE:**
If i build with release settings it is working. But in debug it is not. I am Sure that there is nothing different in the settings.
It seems to be an on of failer. I just checked the build settings and it works. Changed it back and it didn't work. Really strange thing.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem. Maybe if you try something like this:

```
XMMATRIX modelViewPort = ((XMMATRIX) world) * ((XMMATRIX) m_viewportMatrix);
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

`XMMATRIX` represents a 16-byte aligned matrix and so you shouldn't return it in a function as the returned value can't be guaranteed to be 16-byte aligned. This would explain the different result you get with x64 build as that changes the alignment of how the memory is allocated.

XNAMath library recommends that you return a `XMFLOAT4X4` instead. To transfer `XMMATRIX` to `XMFLOAT4X4` use [`XMStoreFloat4x4`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.storing.xmstorefloat4x4%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function and to do the opposite use [`XMLoadFloat4x4`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.loading.xmloadfloat4x4%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

Comment: doesnt change the error. If i use `#define _XM_NO_INTRINSICS_`it works fine. I changed the return type to a `std::shared_ptr<XMMATRIX>` so it should be aligned but it does not change much at all. But disabeling the intrinsics works fine. That arithmetic does need those aligned i think

Comment: @BennX It doesn't change the error when you use `XMFLOAT4X4` or are you talking about the error when you use `#define _XM_NO_INTRINSICS_`?

Comment: No if i dont use the define it creates the error (I just added the define after i asked and noticed it works fine). Kind of nullptr stuff. It doesnt change the error if i return an `FLOAT4X4` and parse it in the getter into it and in the MVP transofrmation parse it back to the `XMMATRIX`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else landing here three years later. There's a new VC++ compiler bug causing this if you have /ZI "Edit and Continue" enabled, in spite of using `XMLoadFloat4x4`. (Affects VS 15.3 and 15.4, [reportedly being fixed](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/110426/c-compiler-bug-invalid-sse2-code-alignment.html) in 15.5.)